# Is there a package for using SQL to manipulate Pandas dataframes in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, sql, dataframe

Rather than learn a new package/language, I'd like to use my existing SQL skills to manipulate pandas `dataframes` in Python. Does anyone know of a way to do this, or perhaps a package that will allow me to do this?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with an SQL language implementation for pandas.  Closest I might be able to get you is: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a package called [pandasql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pandasql), which is based on [sqldf for R](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sqldf/versions/0.3-5). It seems quite a bit slower than doing the transformations with the pandas package, but it gets the job done. Just put the SQL query into a string like this:

```
query_string = """
    select * from df
"""
```

Then use the string in the pandasql.sqldf package, as follows:

```
new_dataframe = pandasql.sqldf(query_string, globals())
```

Choose globals() or locals(), depending on the scope you want for your variables.

As I mentioned, it seems a bit slow, but I couldn't find anything else. I may use this from time to time until I become better at Pandas.

Sean

Answer (score 1):

Based on my experience you can almost do everything that can be done using pandas in your sql. I've not seen recent versions of pandas but I remember that sql is even better because using pandas you are restricted to the size of memory. If memory fills out you may crash, something that does not happen using sql commands. You can save your pandas data frame in a `csv` file and manipulate that `csv` file using your sql. [This link](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) and also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16923281/pandas-writing-dataframe-to-csv-file) may help you. Also for importing your `csv` file to your sql, you have not specified what sql you have but [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242757/import-csv-file-into-sql-server) may help you. Other sqls also provide this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My data are already in a pandas dataframe for various reasons. I'd rather not export to CSV, run my SQL, and then import again... Thanks though! I'll check out your helpful links.

Comment: @Sean_Calgary If you are using big data, I recommend you using your sql. I forget to say this in the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

There's actually a new package called dataframe_sql that does just what you're looking for. It's different from Pandasql in that it translates sql directly to pandas methods, which eliminates the slow down caused by that package. If you want information about installation or how it works you can check it out [here](https://github.com/zbrookle/dataframe_sql)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below option for Google BigQuery SQL:

```
import pandas as pd
from google.cloud import bigquery

selectQuery = """SELECT * FROM mydataset.mytable"""
bigqueryClient = bigquery.Client()
df = bigqueryClient.query(selectQuery).to_dataframe()
print(df)
```